# changing of Vuetify Expansion Panel Header font to bold on focus

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to change the regular font style of expansion panel header into font-bold when it has the focus ... I can't find anything of help in the documentation. I probably missing something ... Kindly give me some idea ... thanks in advance ...

Look at the example below:

```
<v-expansion-panels accordion>
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-for="(item,i) in 5"
    :key="i"
  >

    ***<v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>***

    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

this line **Item**
to change the font only if it has the focus or opened

any help is greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

In the expansion panel, you have got a v-model that syncs the index of all the panels that are being open. You can use this to check whether current panels if open or not and then apply the class.

```
<v-expansion-panels
  v-model="panel" //Added v-model here
  multiple
  >
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    >
    <v-expansion-panel-header 
      :class="panel.indexOf(i) != -1 ? 'font-weight-bold': ''" //Applying class here.
    >
      Header {{ item }}
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

Comment: by giving me ideas with your code, i've got the correct solution to my problem here it is: <style scoped>::v-deep .v-expansion-panel--active > .v-expansion-panel-header { font-weight: bolder !important;}</style>

Comment: Don't override vuetify classes when you have a native solution.